# Display contents of Text File in MVC3 Razor

Tags: file, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to display contents of a text file in a view.
So far I have been able to get the following code for the controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowFile()     
{         
     string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\some unc path\\TextFile1.txt");
     var stream = new StreamReader(filepath);         
     return File(stream.ReadToEnd(), "text/plain");      
}
```

I do not know how to go ahead with the view.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Do you want to just display the text or actually process it as a view so you can include razor syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you could `return Content` instead, and it will render whatever you put in directly to the response stream, with the response type of `text/plain`.

Then you don't even need a View.

Also don't forget about disposing of your resources and exception handling. You don't want to put the `stream.ReadToEnd()` in the return call.

Do it like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ShowFile() {         
     string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\some unc path\\TextFile1.txt");
     string content = string.Empty;

     try {
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(filepath)) {
          content = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
     }
     catch (Exception exc) {
       return Content("Uh oh!");
     } 

     return Content(content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but a code snippet would be more helpful. Also can you post code for file download...?

Comment: Code snippet? What do you call the above then? Don't post the same comment in all answers, actually see if the comment is relevant to each one.

Comment: And if you want file download, then use return File like what you have, and there IS no View, just a dialog to save the file.

Comment: Got the content from the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Return Content(yourText) not a file result. That is for file downloads. If you want to set it in a view with other data as well then create a viewmodel class and assign your text to a property in the model.

Comment: i.e.: Razor View expects the following extensions: aspx, ascx, cshtml, and vbhtml. Can I add to these?